# Proof of Baranyai's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Could you give me a full proof of Baranyai's theorem. I looked at a lot of sites but they seem to only give partial proofs. I read that Schrivjer proved it using the max-flow-min-cut theorem but I can't find his proof (for free).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as I was also looking for a reference for the proof. It turned out to be more difficult than I thought to find a proof, but [here is one.](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/ccs_discrete_s2015/ccs_discrete_s2015_lecture2.pdf) See page 18.

To summarize, the proof strategy is to use max-flow as a black box for a rounding argument (it is clear that "fractional partition into $1$-factors" is possible). This rounding is done element by element. The actual statement to induct on is the following:

Let $k\mid n$, $m=n/k$ and $M=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. If $0\leq \ell\leq n$, then there exists $M$ partitions $A_1,\ldots, A_M$ of $[\ell]$ into $m$ parts so that for any $S\subseteq [\ell]$, it occurs in the partitions for exactly $\binom{n-\ell}{k-|S|}$ times.

In the inductive step, we need to choose, in each partition $A_i$, which part to put $\ell+1$ in, and this choice is done by choosing an integral maximal flow in some network that one can build based on the partitions.